# C# STOMP messaging using queue

Tags: c#, .net, message-queue, stomp, apollo

I need to work with STOMP and queues in C# 4.5. (I never before worked with STOMP or queues).
What is the “recommended” way to send and receive STOMP messages using a queue in .Net?

So far I’ve found a C# example which uses Apache.NMS and Apache.NMS.Stomp  to send and receive messages to/from a Apollo message broker. Apollo looks ok (apart from the fact that it is java^^), but the latest version of Apache.NMS/Stomp is from 2013 …is this project still alive?

Comment: You mean the latest official release or the latest commit to the code base?

Comment: It’s the date of the latest official release, but there were only 9 commits (last in August) to the repository this year.

Answer (score 0):

> What is the “recommended” way to send and receive STOMP messages using
>   a queue in .Net?

Note that with Apollo with Stomp has the disadvantage that Apollo (1.7) does not support rich protocol conversion of messages.

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/APLO-267

This means you can exchange messages not between Stomp clients and non-Stomp clients. For example, the message body sent from OpenWire clients will be received in the Stomp client as OpenWire binary encoded.

In other words, all clients should use the same protocol (Stomp or OpenWire) exclusively, for maximum interoperability.

Comment: Yes I’ve seen this… but this is not really a problem for me, because my application only needs to support STOMP.